# How to show pace.js progress of page load in td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pace

I do have a requirement to show the `pace.js` progress on page load in `td` tag rather showing on the middle of webpage.

**My HTML :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/green/pace-theme-center-circle.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Channel</th>
<th>Health</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile</td>
<td class="tdcolor">
  <select >
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Green</option>
    <option value="2">Red</option>
    <option value="3">Amber</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td> <!--show progress bar here></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to show the progress using `pace.js` in third `td` cell ? The reason I'm using pace is because of nil configuration. If it is not possible, could you please guide me with ajax/jquery?

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but it will take a little bit of work.  You'll need to modify the `pace.js` source file, which means you'll need to host or provide your own (modified) copy of it.

The changes you'll need to make are in the `Bar.prototype.getElement` method; see the modified function below for an example.  You can copy that code exactly, or modify it if you want.

Those changes basically redirect the `targetElement` variable to point to your `td` cell, and also set the progress indicator to use relative positioning so it displays inside the cell.

```
Bar.prototype.getElement = function() {
  var targetElement = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[2];
  if (this.el == null) {
    targetElement = document.querySelector(options.target);
    if (!targetElement) {
      throw new NoTargetError;
    }
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.el.className = "pace pace-active";
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/pace-done/g, '');
    document.body.className += ' pace-running';
    this.el.innerHTML = '<div class="pace-progress">\n  <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>\n</div>\n<div class="pace-activity"></div>';
    targetElement = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[2];
    if (targetElement.firstChild != null) {
      this.el.style.position = "relative";
      targetElement.insertBefore(this.el, targetElement.firstChild);
    } else {
      this.el.style.position = "relative";
      targetElement.appendChild(this.el);
    }
  }
  return this.el;
};
```

I can't provide a working example here because the entire `pace.js` file is too large, but if you replace the standard `Bar.prototype.getElement` with the one above, it will insert the progress indicator into that `td` cell.

---

**[Pace.js License](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/blob/8f5c7cfc339b864354ac120f1bc7657861c8dc27/LICENSE): (*included for attribution*)**

Copyright (c) 2013 HubSpot, Inc.

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: Many Thanks, you are awesome. It works really well. Didn't expect this. I could see the progress bar is not comfortable in the `td` tag. Any suggestions to decrease the size of the progress bar, I'm actually calling this in many `td` blocks on a single web page, so would like to keep it as small as possible. 
Once again I thank you so much for your help... :)

Comment: @harshavmb Happy to help. You should be able to adjust the size of the progress indicator through CSS. Try targeting the `pace-progress` or `pace-progress-inner` classes. Or you could set a max size on the `td` element itself and make sure the progress indicator fills that space but doesn't overflow (causing a scroll bar).

Comment: If you're not worried about seeing the edges of the progress indicator, you could try just adding `td { overflow: hidden; }` to the bottom of the CSS.

Comment: (Also, you might want to also add the license text from Pace.JS to your fiddle, since you're using the code there.)

Comment: Cool adding `td { overflow: hidden; }` and changing few parameters really worked. I would like to thank you very much for your help today. Thanks for suggestion on licensing thing.

Comment: @harshavmb Glad to be able to help!